# Deploying Axis2 Webservice on Jetty Programatically

Tags: web-services, jetty, apache-axis

I have created a Simple Axis2 Java WebService in Eclipse. I am trying to deploy the same programatically in jetty (embedded jetty)

```
WebAppContext webAppContext = new WebAppContext();
webAppContext.setDescriptor(webAppContext + "/WEB-INF/web.xml");
webAppContext.setResourceBase(".");
webAppContext.setContextPath("/");
```

When i hit the server from browser i am just seeing directory structure (Directory: /) of my project, which shows me all the folders in my project as links...

when i click on webcontent folder its showing  default html page i created index.html

but i am not able to get the webservice wsdl path from this.